# Problem with understanding Buyer address

Tags: transactions, remix, addresses

My account address on Remix IDE is 0xCA3…a733c and wallet address is 0x147…C160C. Following is my code obtained from [Solidity Tutorial](https://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/solidity-tutorial). In this code, buyer address is passed as an argument. I have got 3 addresses in the image, which one is the buyer address? Also in the log file I have “to” and “from” addresses, please tell me which one is the buyer address?

```
pragma solidity 0.5.4;
contract MyContractEtherEvents {
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
    address payable wallet;
    event Purchase(
        address indexed _buyer,
        uint256 _amount
    );

    constructor(address payable _wallet) public {
        wallet = _wallet;
    }

    function() external payable {
        buyToken();
    }

    function buyToken() public payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += 1;
        wallet.transfer(msg.value);
        emit Purchase(msg.sender, 1);
    }
}
```

The log file is given below:

> transaction hash
>     0xa4484b15bd6e83c5377bbc4e21f69e8c208a02c3ea0187ffa77cb29c9352df6e 
>   from  0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c  to
>     MyContractEtherEvents.balances(address)
>   0x692a70D2e424a56D2C6C27aA97D1a86395877b3A  transaction cost  23832
>   gas (Cost only applies when called by a contract)  execution cost
>     1152 gas (Cost only applies when called by a contract)  hash
>     0xa4484b15bd6e83c5377bbc4e21f69e8c208a02c3ea0187ffa77cb29c9352df6e 
>   input     0x27e...a733c  decoded input    {   "address ":
>   "0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c" }  decoded output    {
>     "0": "uint256: 4

The image of the project is:

[image: Problem with understanding 3 addresses]

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x147 ...` is going to the `constructor` and ultimately to `wallet` in the code.

`0xCA3 ...` is `msg.sender`

`0x692 ...` is the contract. Remix looks after that for you, but raw transactions would be `to` the contract, `from: 0xCA3 ...` and about `0x147 ...` which is being passed as `msg.data` and unpacked by functions like `buy() ... {` which uses it.

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

I realize it's a contrived example from a tutorial and maybe isn't finished yet. But just to clarify the comments. This might make more sense:

```
    balances[msg.sender] += msg.value; // 1:1 trade
    wallet.transfer(msg.value);
    emit Purchase(msg.sender, msg.value); // that's what happened.
```

Comment: This means 0xCA3 ... is the buyer because it is sending Ether. I can't understand what is the purpose of '1' in "emit Purchase(msg.sender, 1)", please guide me.

Comment: It looks like a token contract that is merely accounting, so the buyer "gets" one token with ` balances[msg.sender] += 1`. Then the contract forwards eth received to the wallet, which must be the guy who deployed the contract. He wants the money. It's not particular about how money was sent. Anything will do, but that is probably later in the tutorial.

Comment: I guess `1` is implied by `+= 1`. It would make more sense to do something like `+= msg.value`.  That way it would trade money in for tokens at a ratio of 1:1.